# Deploying Django web app - 503 Service Unavailable

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to deploy a Django web application. I'm deploying it using cPanel and the functionality "Setup Python App". The application is working on localhost on my machine.
However, when deployed I keep getting a 503 error saying

`Service Unavailable! The server is temporarily busy, try again later!`

I have added my domain name into the `ALLOWED_HOSTS` list in `settings.py`, so that's not the issue.


I have also tried deploying an empty `Django` app but the result was the same. Using an SSH connection, I tried running `python manage.py runserver` and there were no issues. Therefore, I guess the problem is not in the app.

After an attempt to the URL I get the following in the error log:

````
2020-11-04 18:49:21.400909 [INFO] [2117345] [<ip>#APVH_www.<domain_name>.com:443] connection to [uds://tmp/lshttpd/APVH_www.<domain_name>.com:443:Django_Project-master_.sock] on request #0, confirmed, 0, associated process: 0, running: 0, error: No such file or directory!
2020-11-04 18:49:21.400923 [INFO] [2117345] [<ip>#APVH_www.<domain_name>.com:443] connection to [uds://tmp/lshttpd/APVH_www.<domain_name>.com:443:Django_Project-master_.sock] on request #0, confirmed, 0, associated process: 0, running: 0, error: No such file or directory!
2020-11-04 18:49:21.400929 [NOTICE] [2117345] [<ip>#APVH_www.<domain_name>.com:443] Max retries has been reached, 503!
2020-11-04 18:49:21.401018 [NOTICE] [2117345] [<ip>#APVH_www.<domain_name>.com:443] oops! 503 Service Unavailable
2020-11-04 18:49:21.401020 [NOTICE] [2117345] [<ip>#APVH_www.<domain_name>.com:443] Content len: 0, Request line: 'GET /djangotest/ HTTP/1.1'
2020-11-04 18:49:21.401021 [NOTICE] [2117345] [<ip>#APVH_www.<domain_name>.com:443] Redirect: #1, URL: /
2020-11-04 18:49:21.401038 [INFO] [2117345] [<ip>#APVH_www.<domain_name>.com:443] abort request..., code: 4 
2020-11-04 18:49:28.166441 [INFO] [2117345] [<ip>#APVH_www.<domain_name>.com:443] File not found [/home/<user>/domains/<domain_name>.com/private_html/robots.txt] 
2020-11-04 18:49:28.166473 [INFO] [2117345] [<ip>#APVH_www.<domain_name>.com:443] File not found [/home/<user>/domains/<domain_name>.com/private_html/404.shtml] ```
````

Comment: Did you add a Procfile

Comment: Isn't a procfile something specific for Heroku? When the app is created, a ```passenger_wsgi.py``` file is automatically created. It's responsible for the entry point.

Comment: anyone could find solution? i have same problem like this

Answer (score 0):

Did you change the contents of passenger_wsgi.py?  I had a similar issue and copied the data from my wsgi.py file and put it in the passenger file.  After that, I was able to connect hope this works.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for the suggestion. However, by default there is a a response returned from the ```passenger_wsgi.py``` file that says "It works" and the version of Python. This message is never shown in the html. I also tried copying the data from my ```wsgi.py``` into ```passenger_wsgi.py``` and still not getting it to work (it's never loading).